# What does "(new Type [n]) + 1" returns?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

By referring to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/, it is said that the `new` operator returns a pointer to the beginning of the new block of memory allocated. Let's assume again that any pointer has the feature of pointer arithmetic, which can make it true that `p + 1` points to the next position in memory if `p` is a pointer.
Based on the above assumptions, I have tried the following block,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int * ptr = (new int [4]) + 1;
    ptr[3] = 2;
    cout << ptr[3] << endl;
    /*Before delete the dynamic allocated memory, 
      it should be necessary to let ptr point to the 
      beginning of it, add one line to do that:
      --ptr;*/
    delete [] ptr;
}
```

I expected that `ptr[3]` should goes beyond the range of newly allocated memory.  However, the result still give `2`. Why the pointer arithmetic become useless? Or is it really `new Type` returns an object of `*Type`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Accessing elements beyond the bounds of an array is undefined behavior. The program may not crash immediately, or at all. The damage is still done, though.

Comment: It returns a pointer to the second element of the allocated array and causes a memory leak.

Comment: However, it does not happen. Why? Although I make it stupid for letting accessing elements beyond the bounds  of an array.

Comment: Because the memory allocator allocated more memory than you requested, for example to round up to a convenient memory boundary.

Comment: Oh, before today, I only know that `new int [4]` will allocate `4*4 -> 16` bytes.

Comment: *At least* 16 bytes. There's nothing that says it can't allocate more, and there's also nothing that says the next piece of memory is inaccessible. What actually happens is that sbrk() expands the process memory by the quantum requested, which is probably several K at a time, then the allocator subdivides that for the next few allocations.

Comment: But how to explain the result is still `2`, I thought the value should be an unexpected number.

Comment: Because in this case the memory existed and was accessible and you put 2 into it. If it wasn't accessible, the assignment would have failed, not the subsequent read. Your expectations are a bit strange.

Comment: @Life: It's 2 because that's what you wrote there, and nothing else changed it before you read it back. Memory doesn't stop acting like memory just because you're accessing it in a dodgy way.

Comment: I see. I originally want to test the idea that if the pointer arithmetic still works on the object which `new` returns? Thanks.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. Your answer expands my vision.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic works on pointers, within the constraints that have been mentioned here. The fact that you used dynamic allocation really has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Life: Yes, pointer arithmetic works just like it does within any array; including giving undefined behaviour if it takes you outside the array.

Comment: @EJP I really hope `ptr[3] = 2` will invalid. I originally want to test the idea that if the pointer arithmetic still works on the object which new returns.

Comment: Your hope is baseless. It is undefined behaviour. You got lucky. Don't rely on it. Next time you may get a SIGSEGV. There nothing that says you've to get that either. It's undefined. Your computer can blow up, or rehang your toilet rolls by the underhand method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected that `ptr[3]` should goes beyond the range of newly allocated memory.

It does indeed. You need to be careful not to do that, since (as you've noticed) that's an error that often can't be detected. Dynamic analysis tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) can help diagnose these problems, but not perfectly.

> However, the result still give 2.

That means that there happened to be accessible memory beyond the end of the array, so the invalid access couldn't be detected. Instead, it overwrote memory that didn't belong to the array - perhaps it was unused, or perhaps you've overwritten some other data, which will cause baffling errors later.

> Why the pointer arithmetic become useless?

It's as useful as any pointer arithmetic. Pointer arithmetic can't detect the end of an array, so you get undefined behaviour if it takes you out of range.

> Or is it really `new Type` returns an object of `*Type`?

`new Type[]` returns a `Type*` pointer to the allocated array. That behaves just like any other pointer, so adding one gives you a pointer to the second element.

`delete [] ptr` also gives undefined behaviour, since `ptr` no longer points to the start of an allocated array.

Answer (score 2):

Going beyond boundary is undefined behavior.

You may get different results when compiled by differet compiler, different compilation flags, even running at different time. You computer may blow off and your monitor may burn.

Return a correct value is one of undefined behaviors too.

Answer (score 1):

```
int * ptr = new int [4];
```

will point to `ptr[0]`, so

```
int * ptr = (new int [4]) + 1;
```

will pont to `ptr[1]` and you will not be able to free `ptr` unless you do something like `delete (ptr--)`;

Comment: I don't understand who will point to ptr[1]? is it ptr itself?

Comment: Thanks, @SaniHuttunen , you're right. Anywat, it isn't a good practice.

Comment: @Life . I didn't explain myself clearly. What I wanted to mean is that doing `int * ptr = (new int [4]) + 1;`, ptr will point to the next (increased by `sizeof(int)` ) address to the allocated by `new int[4]`

Comment: Yes, I think so. But is there any way to test this idea?

Comment: You *have* tested it, and you got lucky. Don't rely on it, and don't think it's something you should be testing.

Comment: @Life Testing what happens writing out of array bounds doesn't seem very useful. Bad things will happen. Best of them will be a crash with SIGSEGV. Use containers to avoid dealing with array bounds, or be very carefull if you're managing memory and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ allows you to assign/read values to/from out of bounds memory, as this is undefined behavior.

For instance, this is valid code:

```
int *array = new int[10];
array[10] = 5;
std::cout<<array[10];
```

However, doing this you could damage other data structures, if they happen to have memory allocated adjacent to your array.

Comment: No it doesn't. It allows you to use a pointer *value* one past the end, but dereferencing it is undefined behaviour. Re your edit, either it is allowed or it is undefined behaviour. You can't have it both ways. -1

Comment: @EJP I only said you are allowed to "assign" and now edited also the "read" part. I did not say anything about dereferencing.

Comment: A distinction without a difference. You can't read from or assign to out of bounds memory without dereferencing the pointer that points to it, as in your example. The 'as' part doesn't even make sense.